# When Effector animate, amount of liquid particles decrease

Tags: rendering, particles, physics, fluid-simulation

After Fulfill the vessel with liquid. I have to add rotating blades to the vessel. and applied it, effector.  when blades are rotating, the amount of liquid particles is decreases. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are they being pushed through the vessel or just a reduction in particle count?  By the way you can include images in your question if you [edit] your post. :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here is the Image link.   https://ibb.co/Hd6fWKr